# Why isn't my DHCP server working?

Tags: linux, dhcp, dhcp-server

I am trying to setup a DHCP sever with my Raspberry pi, but the service **isc-dhcp-server** cannot be restarted.

Why isn't the service being restarted?

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X  
          inet6 addr: fe80::3d41:3edd:7319:617e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X  
          inet addr:169.254.6.116  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f16d:b76f:795e:d4ff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:299 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:40462 (39.5 KiB)  TX bytes:20406 (19.9 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:16656 (16.2 KiB)  TX bytes:16656 (16.2 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X  
          inet addr:192.168.0.102  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::704a:b2ae:8ac9:48e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1022 errors:0 dropped:11 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:726 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:125229 (122.2 KiB)  TX bytes:114072 (111.3 KiB)
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet dhcp
    address 192.168.2.1
    netmask 255.0.0.0

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**

```
ddns-update-style none;
log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {

        option routers                  192.168.2.1;
        option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;
        option broadcast-address        192.168.2.255;
        option domain-name-servers      194.168.2.1;
        option ntp-servers              192.168.2.1;
        option netbios-name-servers     192.168.2.1;
        option netbios-node-type 2;
        default-lease-time 86400;
        max-lease-time 86400;

        pool {
                range 192.168.2.2 192.168.2.254;
        }

        host gateway {
                hardware ethernet x;
                fixed-address 192.168.2.1;

        }

}
```

**service isc-dhcp-server restart**

```
Job for isc-dhcp-server.service failed. See 'systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

**systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service**

```
Mar 25 20:33:55 raspberrypi dhcpd[1146]: 
Mar 25 20:33:55 raspberrypi dhcpd[1146]: No subnet declaration for wlan0 (192.168.0.102).
Mar 25 20:33:55 raspberrypi dhcpd[1146]: ** Ignoring requests on wlan0.  If this is not what
Mar 25 20:33:55 raspberrypi dhcpd[1146]: you want, please write a subnet declaration
Mar 25 20:33:55 raspberrypi dhcpd[1146]: in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Mar 25 20:33:57 raspberrypi isc-dhcp-server[1138]: Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
Mar 25 20:33:57 raspberrypi isc-dhcp-server[1138]: failed!
Mar 25 20:33:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 25 20:33:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
Mar 25 20:33:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit isc-dhcp-server.service entered failed state
```

**EDITED**

**/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server**

```
# Defaults for isc-dhcp-server initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server
# installed at /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server by the maintainer scripts

#
# This is a POSIX shell fragment
#

# Path to dhcpd's config file (default: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).
#DHCPD_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

# Path to dhcpd's PID file (default: /var/run/dhcpd.pid).
#DHCPD_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid

# Additional options to start dhcpd with.
#       Don't use options -cf or -pf here; use DHCPD_CONF/ DHCPD_PID instead
#OPTIONS=""

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#       Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACES="eth1"
```

Comment: You don't have any network adapters talking to that subnet.  Your WLAN port is *not* on 192.168.2.xxx, so it can't talk on it.  You probably want to assign it to the fixed address  192.168.2.1, or assign one of the eth's, if that's what you are working towards.  Do you have a INTERFACES line in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`

Comment: @infixed - I have updated the question including the /etc/network/interfaces information.

Comment: well, two things.  That `/etc/network/interfaces` leads off `eth1` with a `dhcp` option.  That's indicating it as a dhcp *client*. Set it up as static. Also, apparently the `isc-dhcp-server` depends on information in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` that you have not shown yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `/etc/network/interfaces`, you need to change the stanza for eth1 to look like

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

You seem to have `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` in hand now